# cover image not adding to mp3 using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

The cover image is not adding to the mp3 file

Here is my code : `shell_exec("ffmpeg -y -i ./tmp/tmp -i ./cover.jpg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -metadata title=" . escapeshellarg($title) . " -metadata artist='Tuneraja.com' -metadata album='' -metadata year='' -metadata publisher='Tuneraja.com' -metadata copyright='respected owner' -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 64k -filter:a 'volume=1.0' ./tmp/" . escapeshellarg($fileTitle) . ".mp3 2>&1"); create_mp3($title, $duration, 0, "./tmp/$fileTitle.mp3", $tags);`